# changing the text of a button using javascript event listener

Tags: javascript, dom, button, dom-events, event-listener

I have a simple button that when clicked, the text on the button will change using a event listener. However, I want to add some logic to the code so that when I click it again it just goes back to the original text. I am fairly new to javascript and trying to advance my skills.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Event Listeners JS</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <button>Click Me</button>

   <script>
     document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       e.target.textContent = "I was clicked"; //Changes click me to I was
     });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simply `if` on the textContent to know what to change it to.  Granted you need to preserve what it originally was to be able to change it back.  That could be done with a dataset property though

Comment: Curly Braces { } are used to group statements. So if you need to execute only 1 statement you don't need them. Otherwise if you need to associate multiple statements with **if....else, for, while, ...** you have to add curly braces around those statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Taplar suggested :

EDIT: to make it even cleaner you can single line if statement:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    (e.target.textContent === 'Click Me') ? e.target.textContent = "I was clicked" : e.target.textContent = "Click Me"

});
```

Older answer without single line if statement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Event Listeners JS</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <button>Click Me</button>

   <script>
     document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       //checking the text content in the button if its Click Me
       if(e.target.textContent === 'Click Me'){
       e.target.textContent = "I was clicked"; //Changes click me to I was
         //if its not Click Me it will change back to Click Me
         } else {
           e.target.textContent = "Click Me"; //change back to Click Me
         }
     });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more dynamic solution (no hardcoded values in the handler, it will automatically track what the original text was), you could do it like this:

```js
const toggleTextOnClick = (text, el) => {
    let originalText = el.textContent;
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.textContent = text;
        [originalText, text] = [text, originalText];
    })
}

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
toggleTextOnClick("I was clicked", btn);
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is this:

```js
     document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let textContent = e.target.textContent;
        if (textContent == "Click Me") {
            e.target.textContent = "I was clicked";
         }
         else {
           e.target.textContent = "Click Me";

         }
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Event Listeners JS</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <button>Click Me</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Event Listeners JS</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <button>Click Me</button>

   <script>
     document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if(e.target.textContent == "Click Me")
            e.target.textContent = "I was clicked"; //Changes click me to I was
        else
            e.target.textContent = "Click Me"; //Changes click me to I was
     });
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have added if...else block. Now if button's text is Click Me, statement under if gets executed otherwise statement under else get executed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let last = e.target.last;
    if (last) {
    e.target.last = e.target.textContent;
    e.target.textContent = last;
  } else {
    e.target.last = e.target.textContent;
    e.target.textContent = "I was clicked";
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```